# Why regular expression not working in sql server select statement using like

Tags: sql-server, regex, azure-sql-database

I am new to sql-server and I tried to select all records starting with AB followed by 1, 2 or 3 digits.I tried the following query but it is not working. If I remove the * than it works but skips the records with 1 and 2 digits. I am using SQL-Server 2012. Please help!

```js
select userid from registrations 
where userid like 'AB[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*'
```

Comment: SQL Server doesn't really support regular expressions with the `LIKE` operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
select userid from registrations 
where userid like 'AB[0-9][0-9][0-9]' 
or userid like 'AB[0-9][0-9]' or userid like 'AB[0-9]'
```

Note that SQL Server supports [limited pattern matching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187489.aspx)

You can also check [Working with Regular Expressions](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlclr/archive/2005/06/29/regex.aspx) which will help you to use Regex via CLR

Answer (score 6):

Simple answer: `LIKE` patterns are not regular expressions.

The pattern syntax is [described in the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx). There are no quantifiers.

---

That being said, *even within regular expressions* `AB[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*` doesn't make sense.
`[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]*` is equivalent to `[0-9]*`, in other words, even if `LIKE` would support regex, this would very probably not do what you intend.

Comment: Thank you, I will read the link. You are right. What about this AB[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?

Comment: So you want to match 0-3 digits? Here's an idea. `userid LIKE 'AB%' AND LEN(userid) <= 5 AND ISNUMERIC(SUBSTRING(@userid, 3, 3) + '0') = 1`? In the long run, deconstructing the string into its parts and checking them individually is more flexible than building X `LIKE` patterns.

Comment: I think I will switch to the proper regex in sql :) Thanks.

Comment: That will most likely be slower. Depends on the situation if you care about the performance hit of invoking the CLR (measure and decide).